# Why my .jpg files are saved as .tmp?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am following a tutorial from Laracasts, for uploading files. Here in the example I will upload a jpg file or png file, and in my images folder I get a file with different name and with a different extension. Why is that?

This is how I am moving the uploaded file.
[image]

And here is how the files are saved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You better send also the filename:

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

You'll probably be able to (not tested)

```
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName());
```

Also, check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: How do I know the name of the file if users are the ones uploading different images? Is it mandatory?

Comment: `$name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (No need to use `public_path`):

```
public function store()
{
    $targetPath = 'images'; // For "public/images"
    $file = Input::file('image'); // If "image" is the name of the file input
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($targetPath, $fileName);
}
```